# What does it mean to "Read mail in all mailboxes"?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I'd like to know what it means when a Microsoft Graph application has the `Mail.Read` permission that says *Read mail in all mailboxes*.

Does this mean that such an application can read all mailboxes of every user in the entire company or what *all* mailboxes are they?

The admins won't grant me this permission as they justifiably think it might be a god-mode. Is it?

Comment: here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75431610/microsoft-graph-read-mail-from-outlook-com-account-using-app-only-authenticatio) which has similar scenario, I left comment their. The answers are the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's see the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) here:

> Microsoft Graph lets your app get authorized access to a user's
> Outlook mail data in a personal or organization account. With the
> appropriate delegated or application mail permissions, your app can
> access the mail data of the signed-in user or any user in a tenant.

Let's see the [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which requiring this api permission:

> Get the messages in the signed-in user's mailbox (including the
> Deleted Items and Clutter folders).

But if the `Mail.Read` you [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) is `Application   Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite`, then

> can get messages in another user's mail folder

I'm afraid it is really the god-mode you said. But please note, it doesn't mean , you invite my outlook email address into your company's tenant then you can use this api to read the emails in my outlook email address.

Comment: I'm not so much afraid about ordinary outlook-accounts, but when this setup can read emails of all the employees within an organisation then Microsoft really screw that up

Comment: the most common scenario is, I have a work account like `userA@tenantName.onmicrosof.com`, and you have a work account `userB@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com`, both of the accounts doesn't have mailbox feature by default, then the company bought licenses like M365 E3 license and assign license to the accounts, then both of the accounts can send/receive email via account name. The `Application` API permission is not recommended being used indeed, but it just like a feature, you may won't use it, but you need to have it.